# sparklyr How to add '.option("overwriteSchema", "true")' to saveAsTable() on databricks

Tags: r, apache-spark, sparkr, sparklyr

I am running the below code in databricks to save a table using sparklyr

```
library(sparklyr)
library(dplyr)

sc <- sparklyr::spark_connect(method = "databricks")

dat <- sparklyr::spark_read_table(sc, "products.output")
dat <- dat %>% dplyr::mutate(x = as.character(x), y = as.character(y)) 

%sql
drop table products.output

sparklyr::spark_write_table(x = dat , name = "products.output")

org.apache.spark.sql.AnalysisException:
The schema of your Delta table has changed in an incompatible way since your DataFrame or 
DeltaTable object was created. Please redefine your DataFrame or DeltaTable object
```

Is there anyway I can overwrite the schema?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Same approach as the answer of [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/77365686/how-to-add-optionoverwriteschema-true-to-saveastable-in-sparkr?rq=2). Following the docs of [`sparklyr::spark_write_table`](https://spark.rstudio.com/packages/sparklyr/latest/reference/spark_write_table.html), add another argument as `options=list(overwriteSchema="true")`. This Databricks doc may help: https://docs.databricks.com/en/delta/update-schema.html#explicitly-update-schema-to-change-column-type-or-name

```
sparklyr::spark_write_table(x = dat, name = "products.output",
                            mode = "overwrite",
                            options = list(overwriteSchema = "true"))
```